# Fill area under Student's-t distribution with pgfplot-gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I'd like to draw the pdf of a Student's-t distribution with given degree of freedom *and fill the area under the curve* on a given interval.

The solution I found for Student's-t distribution curve uses `gnuplot`, which somehow makes it harder (for me) to find a way to fill the area. I created the curve the following way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\basefunc{
    gamma((\n+1)/2.)/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(\n/2.))*((1+(x*x)/\n)^(-(\n+1)/2.))
}    
\def\n{7}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[samples=200,ymin=0,xmin=-6,xmax=6]
        \addplot gnuplot [black,thick,smooth,no marks,domain={-6:+6}]{\basefunc};   
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I need something like this (the most important thing is the shading, labeling is not necessary):

[image: Student's t-distribution with two tails]

I appreciate any idea how to fill it similarly.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I've had no problems. Do you have `gnuplot` installed on your system?

Comment: @Ignasi Sorry, I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively plot three times with different domains, using `\closedcycle` for the plots with filling.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\basefunc{
    gamma((\n+1)/2.)/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(\n/2.))*((1+(x*x)/\n)^(-(\n+1)/2.))
}    
\def\n{7}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[samples=200,ymin=0,xmin=-6,xmax=6]
        \addplot gnuplot [no marks,fill=blue,domain={-6:-2}]{\basefunc} \closedcycle; 
        \addplot gnuplot [no marks,fill=red,domain={2:6}]{\basefunc} \closedcycle; 
        \addplot gnuplot [black,thick,smooth,no marks,domain={-6:6}]{\basefunc};   
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you, I prefer this solution. However if I compile it, gnuplot only creates the table for the last function and finally I get the whole functin filled with red. I compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file.tex>` then `gnuplot <file.pgf-plot.gnuplot >` and again with `pdflatex`. What is wrong with the way I compile?

Comment: @grus Only the first of those steps is required. With `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`, `gnuplot` is called in the background to generate the data, which is then read in by `pgfplots`. If I do that one run of `pdflatex` I get the output shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fillbetween` pgfplots library (section 5.7 in pgfplots documentation).

As you want to fill two disjoint areas, will need two commands, one for each area.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\def\basefunc{
    gamma((\n+1)/2.)/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(\n/2.))*((1+(x*x)/\n)^(-(\n+1)/2.))
}    
\def\n{7}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[samples=200,ymin=0,xmin=-6,xmax=6]
        \addplot[name path=A] gnuplot [black,thick,smooth,no marks,domain={-6:+6}]{\basefunc};
        \path [name path=axis] 
            (rel axis cs:0,0) --
(rel axis cs:1,0);

            \addplot[orange] fill between [of=A and axis, soft clip={domain=-6:-2}];

            \addplot[pink] fill between [of=A and axis, soft clip={domain=2:6}];

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However my pgfplot it seems does not include the `fillbetween` library :( I am trying to figure out how to make that work and come back later.

Comment: @grus If `pgfplots` doesn't have `fillbetween` library, you need to update your tex system (at least `pgfplots`).

Comment: Finally I  could update pgfplots (it was not obvious, took awhile to make it work), the code works now. :) Thank you!